# How to use 'is' when type passed in through method?

Tags: c#, syntax

I am trying to pass a type through to a method where I can check if it 'is' a certain type.  However the code I have below does not compile and I am wondering whats wrong.  The compile error is: type or namespace name 'dataType' could not be found.

```
public static List<object> findType(Type dataType)
{
    List<object> items = new List<object>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> entry in DataSource.ItemPairs)
    {
        if (entry.Value != null && entry.Value is dataType)
        {
            items.Add(entry.Value);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`is` operator expects a type name, not the `Type` instance.So the type should be known at compile time.

However you can use, `IsAssignableFrom` method to check if the types are compatible:

```
if (entry.Value != null && dataType.IsAssignableFrom(entry.Value.GetType())
```

Answer (score 5):

`is` is a special compiled construct in c# - you cannot put a variable as the Type, you must write an actual type name.

If you want to check the *exact* type use this:

```
if(entry.Value.GetType() == dataType)
```

If you want to check if it is inherited, you can use this:

```
if (entry.Value != null && dataType.IsAssignableFrom(entry.Value.GetType()))
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to check the type of `entry.Value`.

Try this:

```
if (entry.Value != null && dataType.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(entry.Value))
```

It expects `dataType` to be a type on its own, while it is a variable of type `Type`.

Comment: This is not the same thing as `is`.  It only checks for type equality, not compatibility.

Comment: Remember, that `is` works "recursively". I mean when you check wheter specific derived class is of base type it returns true (including interfaces). Simple comparsion in your case doesn't work in that way.

Comment: Right. Hope it is better now.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use generics and LINQ, things become much easier. Assuming that `DataSource.ItemPairs` is a dictionary type.

```
public static List<T> findType<T>()
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>();
    foreach (T entry in DataSource.ItemPairs.Values.OfType<T>())
    {
        items.Add(entry);
    }
    return items;
}
```

Or even shorter than that.

```
public static List<T> findType<T>()
{
    return DataSource.ItemPairs.Values.OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

entry.Value is an object, every object got GetType() method, which return you a Type object. Type.Equal can compare those types. You can do that without using the "is" word.

You cant use the is word because "is" want to recive an object and not type

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other answers showing how to use a `Type` instance, you could make your method generic. This would allow you to use `is`, but clearly depends on the target type being fixed at compile time:

```
public static List<object> findType<TTarget>()
{
  List<object> items = new List<object>();
  foreach (KeyValuePair<int, object> entry in DataSource.ItemPairs)
  {
    if (entry.Value != null && entry.Value is TTarget)
    {
       …
```